# The average of a product of two random variables in a Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, average

I am reading  a book for Markov chains and there is a problem (simple) but I cannot understand the average of a product of two random variables in the mc.The problem is:

We have a Markov chain in the state space of $X = \{0,1,2\}$ and transition probability matrix:
$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
    1/2 & 1/6 & 1/3 \\
    3/4 & 0 & 1/4 \\
    0 & 1/3 &2/3
\end{bmatrix}$$

with initial distribution:
$\pi_{0}= (1/2,0,1/2).$

Calculating the $\mathbb{E}(X_0X_1)$ we have :
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X_0X_1) & = \sum_{x_0=0}^{2}\sum_{x_1=0}^{2} x_0x_1\mathbb{P}(X_0=x_0,X_1=x_1) \\ 
& = \sum_{x_0=1}^{2}\sum_{x_1=1}^{2} x_0x_1\mathbb{P}(X_0=x_0,X_1=x_1) \\
& = \sum_{x_0=1}^{2}\sum_{x_1=1}^{2} x_0x_1\mathbb{P}(X_0=x_0)\mathbb{P}(X_0=x_0,X_1=x_1) \\
&= \sum_{x_1=1}^{2} 2x_1 \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}(X_1=x1 | X_0=2)
\end{align*}

I cannot understand the last two lines.Can someone explain me all the calculations omitted in order to have these two lines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in the right side of the third line. It should be
$$
\sum_{x_0=1}^2\sum_{x_1=1}^2x_0x_1\mathbb{P}\big(X_0=x_0\big)\mathbb{P}\big(X_1=x_1\,\color{red}{\big|}X_0=x_0\big)\ .
$$
That this is equal to the expression on the previous line follows from the definition of conditional probability:
$$
\mathbb{P}\big(X_1=x_1\,\big|X_0=x_0\big)=\frac{\mathbb{P}\big(X_1=x_1,X_0=x_0\big)}{\mathbb{P}\big(X_0=x_0\big)}\ .
$$
The fourth line follows from the facts that $\ \mathbb{P}\big(X_0=1\big)=\pi_0(1)=0\ $, $\ \mathbb{P}\big(X_0=2\big)=\pi_0(2)=\frac{1}{2}\ $, from which it follows that the term in the outer sum for $\ x_0=1\ $ vanishes, and the only remaining term, for $\ x_0=2\ $, is
\begin{align}
\sum_{x_1=1}^2x_0x_1&\mathbb{P}\big(X_0=x_0\big)\mathbb{P}\big(X_1=x_1\,\big|X_0=x_0\big)\\
&=\sum_{x_1=1}^22x_1\mathbb{P}\big(X_0=2\big)\mathbb{P}\big(X_1=x_1\,\big|X_0=2\big)\\
&=\sum_{x_1=1}^22x_1\pi_0(2)\mathbb{P}\big(X_1=x_1\,\big|X_0=2\big)\\
&=\sum_{x_1=1}^22x_1\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}\big(X_1=x_1\,\big|X_0=2\big)\ .
\end{align}

Comment: I still have some grey areas regarding the line 3 (from line 2) can you please right down all the products in order to be clear to me.Please!!!!I would love to.Thank you very much though for your effort.

Comment: All that happens in going from line $2$ to line $3$ is that $$\mathbb{P}\big(X_0=x_0,X_1=x_1\big)$$ gets replaced with $$\mathbb{P}\big(X_0=x_0\big)\mathbb{P}\big(X_1=x_1\,\big|X_0=x_0\big)\ .$$You can deduce that the second of these expessions is identical to the first by multiplying both sides of the definition of conditional probability given in my answer by $\mathbb{P}\big(X_0=x_0\big)\ \big($and using the fact that $\ \mathbb{P}\big(X_1=x_1,X_0=x_0\big)=\mathbb{P}\big(X_0=x_0,X_1=x_1\big)\ \big)$.

Comment: all right.And what are all the product calculations? This is more confusing to me.Can you please provide them?

Comment: I think there may be some confusion over which line you are referring to. In my answer, I mistakenly referred to the fourth line as "the third line". I have now corrected this.  To see the entire derivation of the fourth line from the third you might have had to manipulate the image of the derivation (as I did on my IPad).  I've now reformatted the entire derivation so that it should now be entirely visible without requiring manipulation.

Comment: I am totally lost now.Anyway thank you for your help.I appreciate it

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears I did not save my previous attempted edits to my answer. I have now redone them.  Is it clearer now.

Comment: I am sorry I cannot understand even now.But for a future visitor on this question I think it will be clear.So I have to make a step back to read again some basic formulations.
For example these two rvs are independent or not? Beginning from line 1.Why he has omitted state 0 and starts summing from 1 to 2?
if I had a full explanations with ALL the calculations of x0*P(x0=x0,X1=x1) and with x1 that it might be clearer

Comment: The terms in the sum with $\ x_0=0\ $ or $\ x_1=0\ $ vanish  because the product $\ x_0x_1\ $ is zero in those cases.  The random variables $\ X_0\ $ and $\ X_1\ $ aren't independent, because they're successive terms in a Markov chain.

Comment: \begin{align*}
&= 1 \cdot 1 \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_0=1)\cdot \mathbb{P}(X_1=1 | X_0=1)\\ &+
1 \cdot 2 \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_0=1)\cdot \mathbb{P}(X_1=2 | X_0=1)\\ &+
2 \cdot 1 \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_0=2)\cdot \mathbb{P}(X_1=1 | X_0=2) \\
&+
2 \cdot 2 \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_0=2)\cdot \mathbb{P}(X_1=2 | X_0=2) 
\end{align*}

using the facts that : $P(X_0=1)=0$ and $P(X_0=2)=1/2$ ()i think here in your answer you have a typo for $P(X_0=2)=1/2$.

Comment: Yes, you've got it.  Your final answer, \begin{align}&2\cdot1\cdot\mathbb{P}\big(X_0=2\big)\cdot\mathbb{P}\big(X_1=1\,\big|X_0=2\big)\\
+&2\cdot2\cdot\mathbb{P}\big(X_0=2\big)\cdot\mathbb{P}\big(X_1=2\,\big|X_0=2\big)\\
=&2\sum_{x_1=1}^2x_1\mathbb{P}\big(X_0=2\big)\mathbb{P}\big(X_1=x_1\,\big|X_0=2\big)\\
=&\sum_{x_1=1}^22\cdot x_1\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\mathbb{P}\big(X_1=x_1\,\big|X_0=2\big)
\end{align}
appears to be the same as mine, so I can't see any typo in my answer.

Comment: You wrote $P(X_0=1)=1/2$ I think is $P(X_0=2)=1/2$

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't looking in the right place, I've now found snd fixed it.